# Trouble connecting mongo to mlab (login failed)

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I try to connect mongo to mlab but got this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWBDo.jpg

```
$ ./bin/mongo.exe mongo ds*****.mlab.com:****/**** -u <username> -p
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongo
MongoDB server version: 3.6.4
2018-04-30T21:59:20.446+0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

I have already created user on mlab database like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWBDo.jpg but it still doesn't work. I'm 100% sure that I did not type the wrong username or password

Comment: add the code instead of linking to images

Comment: @RyanSchaefer edited

Comment: The command should be `./bin/mongo.exe ds*****.mlab.com:****/**** -u <username> -p <password>`. If you run `./bin/mongo.exe mongo ...`, MongoDB will thin you're trying to connect to a database called `mongo` on localhost, which is why it says this line `connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongo`

Comment: @tfogo thank you. it works now